# Delphi: show assigned Frame to Node of Tree View

Tags: delphi, treeview, frame

I have no experience with frames.

How to use a Tree View with frames?
I need to switch among nods of the Tree View and show assigned Frame to the selected node.

Big big thank for help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make any difference if the `Data` of nodes hold a pointer to a frame or any other kind of object, typecast the pointer to the type of object it holds.

Below code adds two frames ('Frame2' and 'Frame3', created by the IDE - much like a new form), as nodes of a TreeView, and sets the visibility of the selected node's frame to true and the deselected one's to false.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
    procedure TreeView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode;
      var AllowChange: Boolean);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2, Unit3;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TreeView1.Align := alLeft;

  with TFrame(TreeView1.Items.AddObject(nil, 'Frame2', TFrame2.Create(nil)).Data) do begin
    Visible := False;
    Parent := Self;
    Align := alClient;
  end;

  with TFrame(TreeView1.Items.AddObject(nil, 'Frame3', TFrame3.Create(nil)).Data) do begin
    Visible := False;
    Parent := Self;
    Align := alClient;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do
    TFrame(TreeView1.Items[i].Data).Free;
end;


procedure TForm1.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  TFrame(Node.Data).Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned((Sender as TTreeView).Selected) then
    TFrame(TTreeView(Sender).Selected.Data).Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: Good. Why do I have such errors switching among Nods: First chance exception at $766EB727. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0049515B in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000059'. Process Project1.exe (3636)???

Comment: +1, code works perfectly. @maxfax, if it doesn't work for you, be more specific about the failure. Did you copy-paste the code, or did you adapt it to your situation? Where do you get the Access Violation?

Comment: Yes, I have created a new project, added 2 frames (Frame2 and Frame3), added new items to TreeView. I have errors on TreeView1Change and TreeView1Changing. There are no errors after I selected all itemes, before - yes.

Comment: @maxfax, How did you add your nodes to the `TreeView`? Sertac's code adds them in `FormCreate`, complete with the associated `TFrame`. If you added nodes to the `TreeView` using any other method, do they have the frames associated with them?

Comment: how to prevent that error if to add other nodes without associated TFrame?

Comment: @maxfax - If you haven't assigned anything to 'Data' of a node, then that 'Data' is nil. So you can test if the 'Data' is 'Assigned' before casting it to a object: `if Assigned(Node.Data) then TFrame(Node.Data)...`

Comment: I have already 1 node (not assigned) and the code on Change: if assigned(node.Data) then TFrame(Node.Data).Visible := True; and on Changing: if Assigned((Sender as TTreeView).Selected) then TFrame(TTreeView(Sender).Selected.Data).Visible := False. And I get the ERROR!

Comment: @maxfax - In the 'OnChanging' event you're testing if 'Selected' is assigned, you should also test (when 'Selected' is assigned) if 'Selected.Data' is assigned: `if Assigned((Sender as TTreeView).Selected) and Assigned(TTreeView(Sender).Selected.Data) then`

Comment: @maxfax - For easier resolution of this kind of AV, put a breakpoint where the exception occurs. When the execution hits the breakpoint, hover your mouse over references, f.i. first on the right parantheses of `TTreeView(Sender)`, then on `Selected`, then on `Data`. When you see a 'nil' you know the cause of the AV.

Comment: Thank you! The last question - if I want to create nods in a design time how can I assign the frames to the nodes?

Comment: @maxfax - You can assign your frame to any node's 'Data' at run-time: `TreeView1.Items[1].Item[1].Data := MyFrame;` Of course 'MyFrame' should have been instantiated by then..