# How to mimic Eclipse Preferences Windows in Delphi 2010 IDE

Tags: eclipse, delphi, user-interface, interface

I'm new to Delphi. I really wanted to build a Preferences Windows in my company legacy system (which uses 'Delphi 2010' today) just like Eclipse's.
[image: Eclipse screenshot]

I could already mimic almost all the items:

Divided the whole screen in 3 panels (one at the left, one at the right and one at the bottom),
On TTreeView inside the left panel, and one TScrollBox on the panel of the right to be able to scroll things if they don't fit on the window for any reason (low monitor resolution or too much options). Even used a TSplitter between panel on the right and the panel on the left.

Here's what I could get:
[image: screenshot of my app]

My doubt is: what should I do to be able to load multiple options once an item inside the TreeView is selected? What delphi component should I use to mimic all this info in the right panel?

Comment: Please consider using a different image host, or even using Stack Overflow's built-in hosting. The one you're using is returning status 403 for me now.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry to use a bad place to store images. I got really frustrated StackOverflow does not allow me to post images. I didn't now how to use this other method. Will try to learn it though. Thanks for pointing me that.

Comment: @user402429: Click on the image toolbar button, select "From the web", enter the picture's URL and click "Upload". The proper markup is inserted automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a [frame](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TFrame) for each page. This is kind of a "sub-form" that you can design visually. Create and destroy them at runtime in the appropriate event-handlers of the tree view.

Comment: forms can be put to a panel as well.

Comment: @Arioch: Sure, but frames are the tool that is designed for that task, while forms are not. I quite often read about subtle problems with tab order etc. with embedded forms.

Comment: Do you happen to know where could I find some code samples? This idea seems to be more ellegant than the previous one.

Comment: I don't know of any samples straightaway, but googling yielded [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576668/delphi-show-assigned-frame-to-node-of-tree-view). It is in terrible need of some refactoring (those `with ((((())))).Data` statements - aargh :-)) and I would probably drop the `Visible` stuff and replace it by calls to `Create` and `Destroy` but that's mostly a matter of taste.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`TPageControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl). Add a [`TTabSheet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabSheet) for each group of controls you plan to have — one for each item in the tree control. Set [`TabVisible := False`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabSheet.TabVisible) for each sheet to keep the tabs from appearing at the top of the page control. Each time an item in the tree control is selected, make the corresponding tab sheet visible by setting the page control's [`ActivePage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl.ActivePage) property. Put controls on the sheets according to the preferences associated with that sheet's category.

Comment: That might work... but wouldn't it be a nightmare to edit those objects if needed?

Comment: If you need to edit them, then edit them. If you don't like the idea of all the controls being buried in the page control at design time, then use frames to design the tab sheets separately, and then put one frame on each sheet. The page control makes it easy to manage the visibility by setting the ActivePage or ActivePageIndex properties.

Comment: if you set `TabVisible := False` for each tab sheet at run-time it would not be such a nightmare...

Comment: You are right. But we have a system here that is built almost entirely this way and to edit it is a pain. But thank you very much for your great advices too. ;)